# Django: Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, ajax, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I've pulled up a dozen similar SO posts on this topic, and have implemented their solutions to the best that I have understood them, yet they haven't worked for me. **Why am I getting this error** `detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."` after using an AJAX Patch request to hit my Django Rest Framework endpoint? *I appreciate your help!*

**Some Details**

- The header tells me "Status Code: 401 Unauthorized"
- I'm on my localHost development server (Postgres)
- I don't get this error with any other django forms or ajax (Get and Posts) requests running on other apps within this application.
- This is the first time I'm attempting a PATCH request
- Ultimately, Once this Ajax Patch request works I, simply want to add `bookid` to the ManyToManyField `books` field in the `api.BookGroup` model
- I've tried to follow the suggestions in similar posts which recommend adjusting the settings.py to allow the right authentication and permission methods.
- referring to [the DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#api-reference), I've also changed the permission classes to `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` which should allow a patch request if I'm logged in when making the request (and yes, I am definitely logged in)
- The form data in the ajax header shows that I am correctly passing the CSRF token and the proper variables:

  ```
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: UjGnVfQTfcmkZKtWjI0m89zlAJqR0wMmUVdh1T1JaiCdyRe2TiW3LPWt
  bookid: 1
  bookgroupid: 71
  ```

**AJAX**

```
function AddToBookGroup(bookgroupid,bookid){
 $.ajax({
    type: "PATCH",
    url: '/api/bookgroups/'+bookgroupid+'/',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN,
        bookid: bookid,
        bookgroupid: bookgroupid
        }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log( 'success, server says '+data);  
    }
 });
}
```

**URLS.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'bookgroups/\d+/$', views.BookGroupUpdateSet.as_view()),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**VIEWS.py**

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, DestroyAPIView, UpdateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated
from . import serializers, models, permissions

class BookGroupUpdateSet(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = models.BookGroup.objects.all()
    model = models.BookGroup
    serializer_class = serializers.BookGroupUpdateSerializer

    def patch(self, request, pk=None):
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
        authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
        bookid = request.Patch['bookid']
        bookgroupid = request.Patch['bookgroupid']
        print("...Print stuff...")
```

**SETTINGS.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authenticate',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.UserProfile"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',  # I've tried this too, same results
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
}
```

Comment: Since you've defined `TokenAuthentication` as authentication class, you have to include token in your HTTP header.

Comment: @Borut How do I do that? I've tried adding `headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '+window.CSRF_TOKEN},` into my ajax (between url:..., and data:..., in which case I get a new error "Invalid token."  (That token is pulled from the django template tag using `window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";` - I've also tried adding `headers: {'X_CSRF_TOKEN': window.CSRF_TOKEN},` and other variations but continue to get the "Authentication credentials were not provided." error

Comment: You have to add API token, not CSRF token. If you check DRF documentation related to [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), you'll see what I mean. It looks like you want SessionAuthentication here, but I can't be sure, changing or updating authentication_classes to include SessionAuthentication will probably fix your issue here. Token authentication is stateless, it doesn't have a session and user is authenticated with token he receives from API login endpoint.

Comment: I tried swapping out `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)` for `authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)` within the view, But I get the same error. Whats odd is that I feel like i've exactly mimicked the setup I have working for other ajax Post calls in this app, and I don't have to pass header authentication or anything other than whats listed in the example above. I'm not sure if its just the PATCH request type that is causing the problem or what.

Comment: Well,  authentication and permission class variables should be class variables and declaring them inside a method won't do anything, but since you set defaults in settings, it's definitely strange that it doesn't work with a valid session, especially if this works elsewhere and the only difference is PATCH method. Change it to PUT and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Django Rest Framework** views, you don't use CSRF Tokens, but custom **DRF** tokens instead (that is what `rest_framework.authtoken` is for). When you create a new user, you have to create his token, like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

    try:
        user = models.User.objects.get(email=validated_data.get('email'))
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = models.User.objects.create(**validated_data)

        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        Token.objects.create(user=user) # -------> Token creation

        return user
    else:
        raise CustomValidation('eMail already in use', 'email', status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

Then, you have to get the token for the user, and send it in the header with key name `Authorization` and value `Token <token>`.

Answer (score 2):

Once your API View requires authentication for being accessed, you need to provide to the request's header the Authorization header:
`Authorization: Token <token>`

So, how do you get this Token? According to the DRF documentation, You need to create a token for each user in your database. So, you have to do manually whenever a new user is created or you can use the DRF Token authentication views by importing and using:

`from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken`

But I suggest You use the django-rest-auth app, It makes easier the Token authentication process in DRF.
https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/